# ESXi "autoboot" to a specific VM

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

Is it possible to install VMware ESXi and when the machine boots, autostart a specific VM ***and*** have that VM take over the local display?

Specifically, this is in the context of running ESXi on either a developer workstation or laptop, and be able to continue using the machine more-or-less normally, while also having other needed VMs (eg development/demo work), but not need to take the performance hit of VirtualBox, VMware Workstation, Parallels, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you cannot view a virtual machines console on the physical ESXi host.  You can configure how and when the virtual machines boot though.  You would need VMware Workstation, Virtual Box, etc to do what you require.  ESXi is designed to be a virtual machine host not a workstation.

Comment: That's what I was afraid someone would come back with - have to reconsider how to provide multiple platforms on a single device for the developer group.